# Deploy a full fledged angular 6 app to elastic beanstalk

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my angular app to the aws elastic beanstalk.The url of the guide that i have been referring to is given here.[Reference link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCwBr.png)

My problem is that the application in aws is turning green and no errors are generated.The snapshot is given here.
[AWS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgaFL.png)

However whenever i am clicking on the url for my app nothing comes up and it is giving me opreation timed out error.Is there something that i am doing wrong.I have tried searching for a lot of reference guides but this was the only one i found.Additionally i am also new to aws.So please help me.

A snapshot of the console output is given here.[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCwBr.png)

Angular.json file is shared here.`{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Final": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "output/dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Final:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Final:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Final:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Final-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Final:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Final:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Final"
}`

This is a screenshot to the error that the AWS is giving me.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnpPq.png)

However i have also included the Dockerfile and  Dockerrun.aws.json in the zipped file that i am uploading.The screenshot of the zipped folder is given here.[zipped folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcLrt.png)

Comment: also if you can post  what is seen in your browser console when trying to load the app would be helpful to the thread

Comment: also please post your `angular.json` here

Comment: @JoelJoseph....please refer to the latest changes in the questions as advised by you.

Comment: Hi please click on the Logs link on the left of the Green health icon and post the logs as well. Most possibly you have an issue with your app since the client was able to hit the endpoint URL but the app returned a 503.

Comment: @Investigator...i have made thye required edits to the question.Please do check it out.